# Zero-knowledge proof of intractibility of NP-complete problems

Tags: complexity-theory, zero-knowledge-proofs

I am not an expert in Zero-knowledge proofs and I am interested in its applicability to general mathematical proofs.

Suppose we're willing to assume that NP-complete problems are intractable and require exponential time algorithms.

Can we construct a zero-knowledge proof of the intractability of Hamiltonian cycle problem, under this assumption? Is it possible without assuming the existence of one-way functions?

Answer (score 3):

"A zero-knowledge proof of the intractability of the Hamiltonian cycle problem" doesn't make sense.  You should refer to the formal definition of a zero-knowledge proof system.  When we talk about a zero-knowledge proof system, it is a zero-knowledge proof system *for a family of statements*.  For the problem to be interesting, the family needs to be infinite.

"The intractability of the Hamiltonian cycle problem" is not a family of statements; it is a single statement.  It doesn't make sense to talk about a zero-knowledge proof in that sense -- you end up with something trivial and degenerate and uninteresting.

In particular, that single statement ("the Hamiltonian cycle problem is intractable") is either true, or it is false.  If it's true, there is a trivial zero-knowledge proof system for it: the prover sends nothing, and the verifier outputs "yes, the statement is true".  If it's false, there is also a trivial zero-knowledge proof system for it: the prover sends nothing, and the verifier outputs "no, the statement is false".  Either way, there exists a zero-knowledge proof system that satisfies the definition.  But this is not very interesting or meaningful.

From a formal mathematical perspective, in the phrase "zero-knowledge proof", you shouldn't think about "zero-knowledge" as a modifier to the word "proof".  Rather, you should think about the phrase "zero-knowledge proof system" as an indivisible term with a specific mathematical definition.  A "zero-knowledge proof system" is not even in the same category as a "proof"; they are like apples and oranges.

Comment: Actually, I am not interested in single statement. It is an infinite family of statements. "Given a cubic graph,  finding HC requires exponential time".

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany, that's not well-defined either.  The complexity of Hamiltonian circuit is a single function -- it's not something that depends on the graph.  If you want the complexity of Hamiltonian circuit *for a single graph*, the complexity is $O(1)$: for each graph, there exists an algorithm that computes the answer *for that graph* in $O(1)$ time.  I suggest you go to the formal definitions.

Comment: No, I am not refering to the complexity of HC. I am interested in proving this statement: "Given a cubic graph, finding a HC requires exponential time". This statement has different truth value for each input graph.

Comment: I made it clear that the input graph is not fixed. I know why it is $O(1)$ for fixed graph.

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany, OK, fine, but that's *a single statement*, so everything I wrote in my answer applies.  That one statement is either true or false.  The mathematical framework of zero-knowledge proofs simply is not set up to talk about a single statement.  Instead, it is set up to deal with an infinite family of statements (each of which might be either true or false).  If you have a family containing only a single instance, everything collapses to trivialities (for technical reasons that are uninteresting and don't shed any light on what we really care about).

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking that for each $n$ we get a proposition $P(n)$, where $P(n)$ is the claim that solving HC for graphs of size $n$ requires exponential time.  But that's not a well-defined notion, because 'exponential time' is itself an asymptotic notion and doesn't make sense when you fix a single size of graph.  Or, to put it another way, if you fix the size of the graph and ask the complexity of HC for all graphs of that size, the answer is $O(1)$: there is a single finite algorithm that solves the HC problem for all graphs of that fixed size.

Comment: @D.W. : ​ I [posted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22732/57159) a non-trivial possible interpretation of the OP's question. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @D.W. : ​ I changed that post's search algorithm again. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 0):

[Ostrovsky and Wigderson](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~rafail/PUBLIC/14.pdf) showed that one-way functions are necessary for zero-knowledge proofs for languages beyond BPP. To the extent that your question makes sense at all, this should show that you do need one-way functions.

Comment: That paper only shows "very weak" one-way functions, rather than the standard definition. ​ [This paper](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/research/ZKcommit-tcc.pdf) gives a tight result. ​ ​​ ​